# How to await and return the result of a http.request(), so that multiple requests run serially?

Tags: node.js, async-await, httprequest, mocha.js, babeljs

Assume there is a function `doRequest(options)`, which is supposed to perform an HTTP request and uses `http.request()` for that.

If `doRequest()` is called in a loop, I want that the next request is made after the previous finished (serial execution, one after another). In order to not mess with callbacks and Promises, I want to use the async/await pattern (transpiled with Babel.js to run with Node 6+).

However, it is unclear to me, how to wait for the response object for further processing and how to return it as result of `doRequest()`:

```
var doRequest = async function (options) {

    var req = await http.request(options);

    // do we need "await" here somehow?
    req.on('response', res => {
        console.log('response received');
        return res.statusCode;
    });
    req.end(); // make the request, returns just a boolean

    // return some result here?!
};
```

If I run my current code using *mocha* using various options for the HTTP requests, all of the requests are made simultaneously it seems. They all fail, probably because `doRequest()` does not actually return anything:

```
describe('Requests', function() {
    var t = [ /* request options */ ];
    t.forEach(function(options) {
        it('should return 200: ' + options.path, () => {
            chai.assert.equal(doRequest(options), 200);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`async/await` work with promises. They will only work if the `async` function your are `await`ing returns a Promise.

To solve your problem, you can either use a library like `request-promise` or return a promise from your `doRequest` function.

Here is a solution using the latter.

```
function doRequest(options) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    let req = http.request(options);

    req.on('response', res => {
      resolve(res);
    });

    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(err);
    });

    req.end();
  }); 
}

describe('Requests', function() {
  var t = [ /* request options */ ];
  t.forEach(function(options) {
    it('should return 200: ' + options.path, async function () {
      try {
        let res = await doRequest(options);
        chai.assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('some error occurred...');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Also, the function returning the `Promise` doesn't need to be declared async as it does no `await`ing of its own :) And catching something just to throw it again is hardly error handling :D `console.log('oh noes!')` is clearly the way to do error handling ;)

Comment: Or just use [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) like `return request(options).catch((e) => { });`

Comment: I think you may need to call `req.end()` within the promise either or else it will never actually send the request?

Answer (score 11):

```
https.get('https://example.com', options, async res => {
    try {
        let body = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');
        for await (const chunk of res) {
            body += chunk;
        }
        console.log('RESPONSE', body);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR', e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const axios = require('axios');

const url = "https://stackoverflow.com";
const {data} = await axios.get(url);
console.log("RES:" + data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The package `request-promise` is mentioned in most voted answer has been deprecated since 2020

Here are some alternatives
https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143

Here is one of those alternatives
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bent

```js
const bent = require('bent')

const getJSON = bent('json')
const getBuffer = bent('buffer')

let obj = await getJSON('http://something.com/json.api')
let buffer = await getBuffer('http://something.com/image.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just pass done to your **it** function. then, after an async req is done, you would add line **done()** after your asserts. If there is an error, you would pass it to the done function like **done(myError)**

https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code for more info

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the second function from the accepted answer readable.

```
    function actuallyDownloadFile( url ) {
      return new Promise ( ( resolve, reject ) => {

        const request = http.get( url );

        request.on( 'response', ( response ) => {
          console.log( 'Doing magic...' );
          resolve( response );
        } );

        request.on( 'error', ( err ) => {
          console.error( 'An error occurred' );
          resolve( err );
        } );

      } );
    }

    async function downloadFile( url ) {
      try {
        const response = await actuallyDownloadFile( url );
        console.log( response );
      } catch ( err ) {
        console.error( err );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
      try 
      {
        const response = await Upload( url );
        console.log( response );
      } 
        catch ( err ) 
       { 
         console.error( err );
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.