# node able to make http request node js aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a lambda function which will make 3 http calls to the endpoints of my service running in the ec2 instance of my pod ,
the aws lambda will be triggered by the cron which I have configured,
I have also added the VPC in the network setting while configuring the aws lambda.

I am using node.js 8.10 to code my lambda handler function , here is my code for the lambda handler function

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  http.get('url1', function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);

  });
  http.get('url2', function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);

  });
  http.get('url3', function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);

  });

  console.log('end request to');
}
```

I also tried this

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
  http.get('url1', function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    context.succeed();
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   context.done(null, 'FAILURE');
  });
  http.get('url2', function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    context.succeed();
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   context.done(null, 'FAILURE');
  });
  http.get('url3', function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    context.succeed();
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
   context.done(null, 'FAILURE');
  });

  console.log('end request to');
}
```

but in both the cases I get this:

```
START RequestId: 0fa5225f-a54f-11e8-85a9-83174efb4714 Version: $LATEST
2018-08-21T14:32:41.855Z    0fa5225f-a54f-11e8-85a9-83174efb4714    end request to
END RequestId: 0fa5225f-a54f-11e8-85a9-83174efb4714
REPORT RequestId: 0fa5225f-a54f-11e8-85a9-83174efb4714
```

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449363/why-is-this-http-request-not-working-on-aws-lambda) answer

Is there any reason why it is not working ?

Comment: You are probably using a more up-to-date version of the Node.js runtime (considering your use of the `async` keyword for the function declaration). That means you don't really want to be using `context` to handle the execution of the lambda. Instead, I would rely on [`async await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470296/how-to-await-and-return-the-result-of-a-http-request-so-that-multiple-request) functionality and simply `return` when your function has finished.

Comment: Also, take a look at [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/) which explains how to use the more recent runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Taking advantage of the (more recent) [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functionality, and also cutting down on boilerplate, you could make your requests like so:

```
const get = async (requestUrl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(requestUrl, function(res) {
            console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
            resolve(res);
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            reject(e);
        });
    });
}
```

Define that function in your lambda file and then you can call it within the handler function like so:

```
const response1 = await get('url1');
```

Then your lambda should run properly.

For more info on using `async` functions with AWS Lambda see [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/) from when they introduced the Node.js 8.10 runtime to AWS Lambda (thus allowing `async/await` functionality).

Comment: tried this running fine in local but getting timeout when I run it inside lambda function have increased the lambda function timeout to be 50 seconds, in local response is coming in miili seconds but not sure why it is timing out in lambda.

Comment: I would guess it is a permissions issue. Double check the VPC config for your lambda and make sure that the EC2 security groups are permitting access on the port you are serving your API.