# getting Task timed out after 59.05 seconds aws lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a lambda function in node 8.10 supported by aws lambda 
 this is with reference to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951099/node-able-to-make-http-request-node-js-aws-lambda)

I am trying node async/await , same code work when I run it in my local(and is not even taking a second to get the response back) but when I am trying it in lambda getting time out error, here the code control is getting inside promise and printing **url urltohit**  with the correct url but after it is getting stuck, have tried different thing like increasing the time in lambda config and even tried node request instead of http but still getting the same error.

'use strict';

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const response = await getRequest(urltohit);
  console.log(response);

}
 const getRequest = async (url) => {
  console.log("Test log");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`url ${url}`);
      http.get(url, function(res) {
          console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
          resolve(res.statusCode);
      }).on('error', function(e) {
          console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
          reject(e.message);
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `callback` after function execution.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = await getRequest(urltohit);
  console.log(response);
  callback(null);
}
```

It's lambda behaviour to keep function running until callback called.
More could be found in official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html)

Comment: with async/await we don't require callback I guess https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: @bhavesh just give a try for callback :)