# getting error 'await is only valid in async functions' from inside an asynchronous function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I assume that this is because some other function that is not async is encasing it maybe? i cannot for the life of me work out what it could be though or how to fix it - (i am pretty much totally new to node so i apologise if this is a really basic question but i couldn't find an answer in any previously asked.)

here is the code:

```
http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
    let data = ''
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        try {
            response =  await query();
        } catch (e) {
            response = e;
        }
        res.write(response);
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

in which *query()* is an async function that waits for a response from a bigquery server. the function works fine if placed before the first *req.on('data')* segment, but not if it is any later in the code than this. Any clues why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `await` keyword is in the unnamed function which occurs as second argument in `req.on('end', () => {...})`. To make that asynchronous, you must write:

```js
req.on('end', async () => {
  let response; // your forgot to declare this local variable
  try {
    response = await query();
  } catch (e) {
    response = e;
  }
  res.write(response);
  res.end();
});
```

But I don't understand what your code does. You collect the `data`, but never use this?

Comment: hi i believe this is the correct answer thank you :) . i removed the section of the code where i handled the data to make it easier to read but maybe this was confusing - should i not do this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because it is nested that it is not receiving a promise back.

Not my answer but i can point you towards a solution given here: [How to await and return the result of a http.request(), so that multiple requests run serially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470296/how-to-await-and-return-the-result-of-a-http-request-so-that-multiple-request)